# How to get coordinate of view in LinearLayout

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

I have a `LinearLayout` which can have many child views. Child views are added programatically.

```
                                                      i need this distance
                                                    <---------------------->
--------------------------------wrapper ln----------------------------------
-                                             ...  cv4   cv3    cv2    cv1 -  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Wrapper ln gravity is setted to right, so every added child view putting right.

For example when I click to "cv4" i need to get the distance from the right side of wrapper linear layout.

Child views are of `LinearLayout` type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call `getWidth()` on the parent LinearLayout and `getLeft()` on the dynamically added view to get the position from the right:

`parent.getWidth() - c4.getLeft();`

You can also hook onto a `OnGlobalLayoutListener` so you can get the co-ordinates every time it changes its dimensions:

```
parent.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
     new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
          public void onGlobalLayout() {
               int right = parent.getWidth() - c4.getLeft();
          }
     }
```